# Jquery, attribut selected to dynamic select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a select in javascript like :

```
        var select = "<select>\
        <option value='1'>1</option>\
        <option value='2'>2</option>\
        <option value='3'>3</option>\
        </select>";
```

And I put this select dynamically in a div with : `$('div').html(select);`

But just after that, i need to add the attribut `selected` to a specific option of THIS dynamic select (because this is in a loop) with value `XXX`. I have `XXX` in a variable.

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/):

```
$('div').find( 'select option[value="' + yourVariable + '"]' ).prop( 'selected', true );
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply set its value, and the selected attribute will be automatically handled:

```
$('div').find('select').val(XXX);
```

---

A better way would be to work with DOM elements instead of raw HTML:

```js
var select = $(document.createElement('select')).append(
    new Option(1, 1),
    new Option(2, 2),
    new Option("third", 3) // first arg is the text, second is the value
);
    
var selectedValue = "2"; // your variable
select.val(selectedValue);
$('div').empty().append(select);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var select = "<select>\
        <option value='1'>1</option>\
        <option value='2'>2</option>\
        <option value='3'>3</option>\
        </select>";

var div = $('div').html(select);

$(div).find('select').val(2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div />
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML Code**

```
</div>
```

You have to use `$("select option[value="+yourval+"]").prop('selected', true)` to select the option dynamically after binding the select element to div.

**jQuery Code**

```
var yourval = '2';
var select = "<select>\
        <option value='1'>1</option>\
        <option value='2'>2</option>\
        <option value='3'>3</option>\
        </select>";

$("div").html(select);


$("select option[value="+yourval+"]").prop('selected', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/q5bo507k/